# How to determine which of the following transformations are linear transformations?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

> Determine which of the following transformations are linear transformations
>
> A. The transformation $T_1$ defined by $T_1(x_1,x_2,x_3)=(x_1,0,x_3)$
>
> B. The transformation $T_2$ defined by $T_2(x_1,x_2)=(2x_1−3x_2,x_1+4,5x_2)$.
>
> C. The transformation $T_3$ defined by $T_3(x_1,x_2,x3)=(x_1,x_2,−x_3)$
>
> D. The transformation $T_4$ defined by $T_4(x_1,x_2,x3)=(1,x_2,x_3)$
>
> E. The transformation $T_5$ defined by $T_5(x_1,x_2)=(4x_1−2x_2,3|x_2|)$.

I believe that it could be A and E. How can I determine this? If someone could show me one I could figure out the rest.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To test whether T is a linear transformation, you need to check that for some vectors $a$ and $b$ and some constant $c$
$$T(a + b) = T(a) +T(b)$$ 
$$T(ca) = cT(a)$$ 
$$T(0) = 0$$
So for example,
A. $T(x_1,x_2,x_3)=(x_1,0,x_3)$
$$T(x_1+y_1,x_2+y_2,x_3+y_3)=(x_1+y_1,0(x_2+y_2),x_3+y_3)=T(x_1,0,x_3)+T(y_1,0,y_2)$$$$T(cx_1,cx_2,cx_3)=T(cx_1,(c)0,cx_3)=cT(x_1,0,x_3)$$
$$T(0,0,0)=0$$
B. $T(x_1,x_2)=(2x_1−3x_2,x_1+4,5x_2)$
$$T(x_1+y_1,x_2+y_2)=(2(x_1+y_1)−3(x_2+y_2),(x_1+y_1)+4,5(x_2+y_2))=(2x_1+2y_1−3x_2-3y_2,x_1+y_1+4,5x_2+5y_2)$$$$T(x_1,x_2)+T(y_1,y_2)=(2x_1−3x_2,x_1+4,5x_2)+(2y_1−3y_2,y_1+4,5y_2)=(2x_1−3x_2+2y_1-3y_2,x_1+y_1+8,5x_2+5y_2)\not=T(x_1+y_1,x_2+y_2)$$
So B is not a linear transformation.

Comment: What about $T(a,b,c)$ ?

Comment: In the example above $a, b$ are vectors and $c$ is a scalar.

Comment: @Yusha It is not necessarily following the format in your problem, it is asking you to plug in two vectors and see if they work according to the transformation given, so it doesn't matter how many terms are there in your given T

Comment: Can you do  B also? I just want to see one more

Comment: @Yusha just added B

Comment: @Samantha Why do you specify $T(0)=0$? That does not need to be checked. Also it is not for some vectors $a$ and $b$, and some constant $c$, the condition is for all vectors $a$ and $b$ and all constants $c$. I'm sorry, this answer is currently incorrect. Downvote. If you correct, do let me know, and I'll reverse it. Also $T(cx_1,cx_2,cx_3)=(cx_1,0,cx_3)=(cx_1,c0,cx_3)=c(x_1,0,x_3)=cT(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ is the correct check for the second condition for function A.

Answer (score 6):

For $T$ to be a linear transformation, two criteria need to be satisfied:

1. $T(\mathbf{x}+\mathbf{y}) = T(\mathbf{x})+T(\mathbf{y})$
2. $T(a\mathbf{x}) = aT(\mathbf{x})$ for $a$ a scalar/constant.

As an example, suppose $\mathbf{x} = (x_1, x_2, x_3)$ and $\mathbf{y} = (y_1, y_2, y_3)$. Let's start with A.

Then, $T(\mathbf{x}) = (x_1, 0, x_3)$ and $T(\mathbf{y}) = (y_1, 0, y_3)$. Now $$\mathbf{x}+\mathbf{y} = (x_1 + y_1, x_2 + y_2, x_3 + y_3)\text{.}$$ It follows that $T(\mathbf{x}+\mathbf{y}) = (x_1 + y_1, 0, x_3+y_3)$.

Is $T(\mathbf{x}+\mathbf{y}) = T(\mathbf{x})+T(\mathbf{y})$?

Now, for a constant $a$, $a\mathbf{x} = (ax_1, ax_2, ax_3)$.

We have $T(a\mathbf{x}) = (ax_1, 0, ax_3)$.

Furthermore, we know $T(\mathbf{x}) = (x_1, 0, x_3)$, so $aT(\mathbf{x}) = (ax_1, 0, ax_3)$.

Is $T(a\mathbf{x}) = aT(\mathbf{x})$?

Repeat this for all of the other $T$.

Answer (score 2):

A linear transformation has this defintion.

$T(\mathbf x+\mathbf y) = T(\mathbf x) + T(\mathbf y)\\
T(c\mathbf x) = cT(\mathbf x)$

Show that this is (or isn't) true for each of the above.

Comment: that's an additive transformation -- it doesn't necessarily scale appropriately

Comment: @William It is adequate in $\mathbb R^n,$ as $T(\mathbf x +\mathbf x) = 2 T(\mathbf x).$  But, yes, $T(c\mathbf x) = cT(\mathbf x)$ should be included as long as I am quoting definitions.

Comment: True, but that will only work if the underlying field is complete, and even then it is a tedious pain to show how it is sufficient in that special case. It is technically correct, but I don't think it is pedagogically useful for someone learning abstract vector spaces for the first time.

Comment: @William, it also needs the fraction field of the image of $Z$ to be dense, I would think? Correct me if I'm wrong, but in that case, a complete non-discrete field of characteristic $p$ should be a problem. See https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Local_field for existence of such fields. Please let me know if I'm wrong, so I can think about it more.

Comment: @jgon You're right of course; my bad

Answer (score 1):

A linear transformation is defined by a set of *homogeneous* linear (i.e. all terms have degree $1$) polynomials, namely of the  form
$$T(x_1,x_2,x_3)=ax_1+bx_2+cx_3\quad(a,b,c\in\mathbf R).$$
A and C alone satisfy this criterion.

Comment: That's a linear transformation from $\mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}$; not a linear endomorphism of $\mathbb{R}^3$

Comment: @William: I rephrased my answer in a more appropriate manner.

Comment: @Bernard I still agree with William, unless $a$, $b$, and $c$ are vectors (which is not what you specified), and then it isn't a homogeneous linear polynomial. You could say it is a polynomial map with each coordinate function being a homogeneous linear polynomial.

Comment: @jgon: That was implicit when I added ‘defined *by a set of* (one polynomial per coordinate of the codomain).

Answer (score 1):

$A$. $$T(a\vec{x})=T(ax_1, ax_2, ax_3) = (ax_1, 0, ax_3) = a(x_1, 0, x_3) = aT(\vec{x})$$

$$T(\vec{x} +\vec{y})=T(x_1+y_1, x_2+y_2, x_3+y_3)\\=(x_1+y_1,0,x_3+y_3)=(x_1,0,x_3)+(y_1,0,y_3)=T(\vec{x})+T(\vec{y})$$

Therefore the first transformation is linear as you correctly guessed. Just repeat the same procedure for B-E and see if it works or not.

Answer (score 0):

Is T in A a linear transformation?

1. Check linearity for addition.

Suppose $T:V \rightarrow W$ .Where $V$ and $W$ are vector spaces over $F$. Let $x_1,x_2,x_3 \in F$ and also let $x_4,x_5,x_6 \in F$. So that $(x_1,x_2,x_3) \in V$ and $(x_4,x_5,x_6) \in V$. Now need to check that $T((x_1,x_2,x_3)) + T((x_4,x_5,x_6)) = T((x_1+x_4, x_2+x_5,x_3+x_6))$.

We have LHS $ = (x_1,0,x_3) + (x_4,0,x_6) = (x_1+x_4,0,x_3+x_6) = $RHS. Hence this holds by definition of vector addition.

2. Check linearity for scalar multiplication:

Let be as above, and suppose $V$ is a vector-space over a field $F$. Then let $a\in F$. Want to prove that:

$aT(x_1,x_2,x_3)=T(ax_1,ax_2,ax_3)$. Hence we have:

LHS $ = a(x_1,0,x_3) = (ax_1,0,ax_3) = $RHS. And this holds by vector scalar multiplication and by property of zero in $\mathbb{R}$.

Hence this is a linear transformation by definition. In general you need to show that these two properties hold.

Comment: If $x_1,x_2,x_3$ are vectors in $V$ and $T:V\rightarrow W$, what is $(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ and how do you define $T$ on something which is clearly  not in the domain?

Comment: ahaha you're right sorry

Comment: @sqtrat , edited now!

Comment: It seems that you assume that $V$ and $W$ are $3$ dimensional with standard basis vectors, otherwise why should $(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ be an element of $V$ in the first place. Either be more general or be more specific.

Comment: @sqtrat could they be more than 3 dimensional?

Comment: Well, in the OP's example, all are either $2$ or $3$ dimensional, but of course there are $n$ dimensional vector spaces for every integer $n$ and infinite dimensional ones as well.

Comment: @sqtrat, yeah of course they exist. But in the question I supposed they were just simple three dimensional vectorspaces, I don't think it's too general for the way the exercise was shown.